# Plotting fresh plot for every iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

How do i plot a fresh new plot for each iteration without stacking plots? And how do i change the X-direction, so the "flow" seems to come from the opposite direction?

Im plotting a window of 3 hours seismic data which changes for every iteration. The seismic data is changing every 8 seconds (ideally) as if it was a live feed. When i run the script it plots every iteration on top of eachother. I've tried to put the figure command at the top of the whole for-loop, but it doesn't help.

To make the data flow from right to left, and not left to right, i've tried to insert set(gca, 'XDir','reverse'), but it still "feeds" from the right.

```
for k = 1:length(AAA)/8*sampleRate 
V=AAA(1+k*8*sampleRate:(3*L)+k*8*sampleRate);
v2=flipud(V);

d1 = length(BPPUdpluk);
s = 1;
output = zeros(round(L/s),d1);

for i=1:length(v2)-d1
  xj2=0;
  yj2=0;
  xy2=0;
  val2=0;
    for j=1:d1
  xj2=xj2+BPPUdpluk(j)*BPPUdpluk(j);
  yj2=yj2+v2(j+i-1)*v2(j+i-1);
  xy2=xy2+BPPUdpluk(j)*v2(j+i-1);
    end
 %  val=xy/(sqrt(xj).*sqrt(yj))
  corr3(i)=xy2/(sqrt(xj2)*sqrt(yj2));
end
toc

corr4 = corr3';
corr4 = flipud(corr4);
Udslag(k)=length(corr4(corr4>=0.25));


figure(6)
red=zeros(1,length(corr4));
red(:)=0.25;
time2 = (0:3/(length(corr3)-1):3);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(time2,corr4,'color',[0 0.4470 0.7410])
xlabel('Time[Hr] - 3Hr window')
ylabel('CC')
%hold on 
plot(time2,red,'r')
set(gca, 'XDir','reverse')
%axis([0 3 -1 1]);
set(gca,'xtick',[])
grid
%hold off
if Udslag(k) <=1
hold on
subplot(2,1,2)
bar(Udslag(k))
set(gca,'Color','g')
hold off
else if Udslag(k) == 2
    hold on
    subplot(2,1,2)
    bar(Udslag(k))
    set(gca,'Color','y')
    hold off
    else
        hold on
        subplot(2,1,2)
        bar(Udslag(k))
        set(gca,'Color','r')
        hold off
    end
end
end
```

I expect the plot to be displayed as a new plot from every iteration, when i run. I expect the x direction to be reversed.

It plots on top of the old plots, and the x direction is still the same.

Comment: Replace `figure(6)` with `figure`. Read the documentation to learn why this fixes your problem (type `help figure` in MATLAB). To reverse the x-axis, set the `XDir` property of the `axes` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you elaborate on the issue with the x-axis? i've tried to do this "set(gca, 'XDir','-')"

Comment: See the docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-XDir Set the property to `'reverse'`.